Some of my basement ceiling lights not working
I have been living here for 2 yrs. Recently the some of the lights on basement ceiling started sparkling or shaking. I replaced one bulb with new one  and again another new one but that one completed died as you can see in the picture on far right. The new bulb didn't work either.
Now today, the light with the cover removed as you can see in the picture also went off and tried removing and putting it back on but it won't light up. This too is a brand new replacement bulb I replaced 3 days ago, so two of the 4 basement lights are out.
What should I do at the moment? I fear having to waste money calling a handyman or electrician but I am no DIY and have no choice but please let me know why this happened and if it's I can easily fix myself without removing any wires or or opening up outlets.



You could try turning off the breaker(main if not sure of the right breaker) and carefully lift the centre post/silver thingy in the centre a bit. Maybe 1/16 to 1/8 inch, no more than that.  If that does not fix it, with your knowledge, an electrician will be helpful.

circut breaker has many switches. i will turn off all and turn back. you are syaing turn off and on right?

Turn off before you have your fingers in the light fixture.  Turn on after finishing.

I'm really not sure what "sparking" and "shaking" mean. Please revise to be more clear.

Pictures are usually helpful but these ones, not so much. In the first picture we see a light not working.  In the second, we see a ceiling, a couple of lights, a vent.  Not clear what you're showing.  What do the misbehaving lights have in common? Are they all in the same fixture?  Do they all turn on and off from the same switch?  Do they all "sparkle" at the same time or at different times?  Do you mean "flicker", as in turn on and off rapidly?  You don't mean actual sparks, as in, fire, do you?

Do the bulbs that don't work any more, particularly the new (only a few days old) ones work in any other fixtures in the house? If they do then the problem is the basement ceiling fixtures and replacement makes sense. If they don't then you may have a bad batch of bulbs (try the same size/type but a different brand) or you may have bad fixtures.

shaking ... are the lights actually moving?
